# How to build android app with Gradle with not the latest version of maven artifact?

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I'm having app that is built with Gradle and it requires maven module `fs`. My android app requires version `1.1` (exists in local maven repo) but it's not the latest version of the module in local maven repository (version `1.2` is in local maven repo too):

```
compile 'name.antonsmirnov.fs:fs:1.1'
```

When trying to build android app i'm getting error:

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve name.antonsmirnov.fs:fs:1.1.
     Required by:
         Ad_gradle:app:unspecified
      > inconsistent module metadata found. Descriptor: name.antonsmirnov.fs:fs:1.2 Errors: bad version: expected='1.1' found='1.2'
   > Could not resolve name.antonsmirnov.fs:dropbox:1.1.
```

How can i force Gradle to use not the latest version of maven module (artifact)?

PS. One more question: if i delete folder `1.2` from local maven repo it does not help (so gradle cached that 1.2 is available and does not compile even after removal).

PPS. Even if i use "+" for version to make Gradle get the latest available, it can't resolve it:

```
compile "name.antonsmirnov.fs:fs:+"
```

error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve name.antonsmirnov.fs:fs:+.
     Required by:
         Ad_gradle:app:unspecified
      > inconsistent module metadata found. Descriptor: name.antonsmirnov.fs:fs:1.2 Errors: bad version: expected='1.1' found='1.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your gradle config for the app where you specify repositories to be used for Maven artifacts.  Depending on your configuration, this may be in your top level `build.gradle` file or the one for the your project (typically `app/build.gradle`.)  You'll need to add `mavenLocal` in order to pick up your local Maven artifacts:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}
```

Comment: i have the following text:
 `repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}` so it should work. If no local maven repo is added it would not find it at all (and does not show that 1.2 is available)

Comment: Did something in the `fs` package meta-data change between 1.1 and 1.2?  More than just the version, such as the package or artifact name/id?

Comment: i think something has been changed but those changes are not desired for the android app. probably 1.2 was some "feature branch" that was denied for merging into master. so i should just skip using 1.2 and stay with stable 1.1

Comment: Sure, that happens with libs sometimes.  What I mean is there could be something different with the packaging details which is causing Maven to not resolve the package correctly.

Comment: i'm able to build the app with maven and i'm almost sure it's gradle issue. any confirmation or walkaround?